# How to load an ObjectModel with submitted values in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, helper, object-model

I'm using an HelperForm to display my form which has multilang features.
I also created a Model with fields (some are multilang).

The problem is, once the user submit the form, how can I fill the data from the submit form into my new model ?

I tried this :

```
$instance = new MyModel();
$instance->validateController();
```

But for some kind of odd reasons, it doesn't save the language fields, only the "direct" fields.

I thought about using `validateFields` and `validateFieldsLang`, but they stop at the first encountered error ; I'd like to list all the possible errors at once.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it from the front or back office?

Admin controllers have this

```
$this->copyFromPost($this->object, $this->table);
```

Thich basically calls the object's validation

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention, but none of them, since it's a module, I'm extending the Module class.